# How to customize a mapping method in Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis, arcobjects

Although it's easy to find the shortest path between two points using `NASolver`, sometimes `NAClassLoader.Load`  failed to map the points to the right road, `NALocator` **only considers the closest distance**.

For example, sometimes we have to judge a point's matching positon according to vehicle's previous tracks, at this time, it will make some mistakes if the `loader` maps the point to the closet road.

In the graph below, because point1 is on the green road, so point2 should also belongs to the green line but not the red ones. **How can I tell the NALocator the right choice?** Will `NALocatorFeatureAgent` work in this condition?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using hierarchy, or network attributes/restrictions to give the priority to certain roads? What's the logic behind preferring the green road over the red one?

Comment: I have updated my question, logic behind preferring the green road is based on the position of the last point , such as point1 in the picture.

Comment: Have you tried route-solving with multiple stops?

Comment: Yes, I can find the route of multiple stops, but some points are matched to the wrong roads.

Comment: Network Analyst calculates the most efficient route in terms of length, time or any other given cost. If according to you it's not, you should modify the network attributes and analysis parameters. Check the tolerance for stops not located on top of a road but next to it, for example. A concrete example of a route result would help because with your image it's indeed difficult to understand why the red road is preferred for going from point 1 to point 2.